# Вопрос по Chart: получение значения Y по известному значению X

Tags: delphi-7, диаграммы

В Chart создал Series1. В проекте юзаю `TForm1.Chart1MouseMove`. Пытаюсь по известному значению X: Double выловить его индекс таким образом: `I:=Series1.XValues.Locate(X)`. Но в результате получаю I=-1, хотя знаю точно, что при движении мышью прохожу через ранее введённые X. Иными словами, я ожидал, что I не всегда равно -1. Нигде не могу найти решение проблемы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По-моему, нет функции, которая возвращает индекс точки по значению Х, поскольку XValue - имеет тип double. Я применял поиск индекса путем деления отрезка пополам до тех пор пока заданное значение не оказывалось между 2-х точек. А потом выяснял - к какой ближе.

Comment: Вынужден возразить. Если бы такой функции не было, то вместо значения функции -1 на выходе  делфя упорно и настойчиво выдавала бы сообщение об ошибке. Эту самую функцию неоднократно встречал в просторах Интернета в тщетных (до сих пор) поисках решения моей проблемы.
BuilderC, у меня вопрос. При применении указанного Вами метода на Chart1MouseMove при количестве в Series значений X более 100 машина не подтормаживает?

Comment: Я, очевидно, неправильно понял Ваш вопрос. На TChart выведена Series, и Вы хотите по известному Х найти индекс точки? Тогда причем здесь Сhart.MouseMove? 

Или Вы хотите щелчком мыши по кривой определить индекс точки?

Comment: На Charte несколько Series (до 16-ти). При движении мышью над Chart рисуется вертикальная линия, пересекающая все Series. Одновременно на Label1, стоящем на форме, выводится текущее значение X. Мне нужно в это же время на других Label-ах выводить текущее значение Y для каждого Series. При нажатии на левую кнопку мыши вертикальная полоса "замирает" на Charte (перестаёт реагировать на движение мыши), а на всех Label-ах сохраняются соответствующие значения X и Y. Извините, что сразу не сказал. У меня работает всё, кроме вывода значений Y для Series.

Comment: Теперь понял. Могу только посоветовать Вам осуществлять вычисление индексов ПОСЛЕ остановки репера. А пока не остановили, удовлетворяться физическими координатами Chart с помощью Сhart.OnMouseMove, CalcYPosValue и CalcXPosValue.

Comment: Я реализовал вариант с поиском индекса значения X методом половинного деления. Если оказывается, что текущее значение X находится между двух точек, то для расчёта значения Y в ход идёт линейная интерполяция. Для всех 16-ти Series эти вычисления я разместил в Сhart.MouseMove, т.е. при движении мыши на 16-ти Label-ах выводятся текущие значения Y и в Edit-е - текущее значение X. В моих Series количество точек разное - от 80 до 115. На работе стоит Пень четвёртый - ничего не подтормаживает. BuilderC - спасибо за идею. Таким образом, я считаю данный вопрос закрытым.